# Upload video files via PHP and save them in appropriate folder and have a database entry

Tags: php

I want the user to be able to upload video files to my site and I want them arranged in proper folders plus a database entry so that later I can know the person who uploaded each particular file.

My HTML form is here:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div><?php echo $message; ?></div>
    <?php echo $max_file_size_tag; ?>
    <input type="file" accept="video/*" ID="fileSelect" runat="server" size="20" name="filename" action="/vids/file-upload.php">
    <select name="course">
        <option value="select" selected>Select</option>
        <option value="java">Java</option>
        <option value="python">Python</option>
        <option value="vb">Visual Basic</option>
        <option value="c">C/C++</option>
        <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

And my PHP is here:

```
<?php

$folder  = isset($_POST["course"]);
$message = "1";

define('DESTINATION_FOLDER','/$folder);

define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 0);

// Upload success URL. User will be redirected to this page after upload.
define('SUCCESS_URL','learn.learnbrix.com');

// Allowed file extensions. Will only allow these extensions if not empty.
// Example: $exts = array('avi','mov','doc');
$exts = array();

// rename file after upload? false - leave original, true - rename to some unique filename
define('RENAME_FILE', true);

$message = "renamed";
// put a string to append to the uploaded file name (after extension);
// this will reduce the risk of being hacked by uploading potentially unsafe files;
// sample strings: aaa, my, etc.
define('APPEND_STRING', '~');

$message = "string append";
// Need uploads log? Logs would be saved in the MySql database.
define('DO_LOG', false);

// MySql data (in case you want to save uploads log)
define('DB_HOST','  '); // host, usually localhost
define('DB_DATABASE','  '); // database name
define('DB_USERNAME','  '); // username
define('DB_PASSWORD','  '); // password

/* NOTE: when using log, you have to create MySQL table first for this script.
Copy-paste following into your MySQL admin tool (like PhpMyAdmin) to create a table
If you are on cPanel, then prefix _uploads_log on line 205 with your username, so it would be like myusername_uploads_log

CREATE TABLE _uploads_log (
  log_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  log_filename varchar(128) default '',
  log_size int(10) default 0,
  log_ip varchar(24) default '',
  log_date timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY  (log_id),
  KEY (log_filename)
);

*/

####################################################################
###  END OF SETTINGS.   DO NOT CHANGE BELOW
####################################################################

// Allow script to work long enough to upload big files (in seconds, 2 days by default)
@set_time_limit(172800);

// following may need to be uncommented in case of problems
// ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","10800");

function showUploadForm($message='') {
  $max_file_size_tag = '';
  if (MAX_FILE_SIZE > 0) {
    // convert to bytes
    $max_file_size_tag = "<input name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='".(MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024)."' type='hidden' >\n";
  }

  // Load form template
  include ('upload.html');
}

// errors list
$errors = array();

$message = '';

// we should not exceed php.ini max file size
$ini_maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
if (!is_numeric($ini_maxsize)) {
  if (strpos($ini_maxsize, 'M') !== false)
    $ini_maxsize = intval($ini_maxsize)*1024*1024;
  elseif (strpos($ini_maxsize, 'K') !== false)
    $ini_maxsize = intval($ini_maxsize)*1024;
  elseif (strpos($ini_maxsize, 'G') !== false)
    $ini_maxsize = intval($ini_maxsize)*1024*1024*1024;
}
if ($ini_maxsize < MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024) {
  $errors[] = "Alert! Maximum upload file size in php.ini (upload_max_filesize) is less than script's MAX_FILE_SIZE";
}

// show upload form
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  showUploadForm(join('',$errors));
}

// process file upload
else {

  while(true) {

    // make sure destination folder exists
   if (!@file_exists(DESTINATION_FOLDER)) {
     $errors[] = "Destination folder does not exist or no permissions to see it.";
     break;
   }

   // check for upload errors
   $error_code = $_FILES['filename']['error'];
   if ($error_code != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
     switch($error_code) {
       case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 
        // uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini
        $errors[] = "File is too big (1).";
        break;
      case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: 
        // uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form
        $errors[] = "File is too big (2).";
         break;
       case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
         // uploaded file was only partially uploaded.
         $errors[] = "Could not upload file (1).";
         break;
       case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
         // No file was uploaded
         $errors[] = "Could not upload file (2).";
         break;
       case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
         // Missing a temporary folder
         $errors[] = "Could not upload file (3).";
         break;
       case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
      // Failed to write file to disk
      $errors[] = "Could not upload file (4).";
      break;
    case 8:
      // File upload stopped by extension
      $errors[] = "Could not upload file (5).";
      break;
  } // switch

  // leave the while loop
  break;
}

// get file name (not including path)
$filename = @basename($_FILES['filename']['name']);

// filename of temp uploaded file
$tmp_filename = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

$file_ext = @strtolower(@strrchr($filename,"."));
if (@strpos($file_ext,'.') === false) { // no dot? strange
  $errors[] = "Suspicious file name or could not determine file extension.";
  break;
}
$file_ext = @substr($file_ext, 1); // remove dot

// check file type if needed
if (count($exts)) {   /// some day maybe check also $_FILES['user_file']['type']
  if (!@in_array($file_ext, $exts)) {
    $errors[] = "Files of this type are not allowed for upload.";
    break;
  }
}

// destination filename, rename if set to
$dest_filename = $filename;
if (RENAME_FILE) {
  $dest_filename = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . '.' . $file_ext;
}
// append predefined string for safety
$dest_filename = $dest_filename . APPEND_STRING;

// get size
$filesize = intval($_FILES["filename"]["size"]); // filesize($tmp_filename);

// make sure file size is ok
if (MAX_FILE_SIZE > 0 && MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024 < $filesize) {
  $errors[] = "File is too big (3).";
  break;
}

if (!@move_uploaded_file($tmp_filename , DESTINATION_FOLDER . $dest_filename)) {
  $errors[] = "Could not upload file (6).";
  break;
}

if (DO_LOG) {
  // Establish DB connection
  $link = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
  if (!$link) {
    $errors[] = "Could not connect to mysql.";
    break;
  }
  $res = @mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $link);
  if (!$res) {
    $errors[] = "Could not select database.";
    break;
  }
  $m_ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  $m_size = $filesize;
  $m_fname = mysql_real_escape_string($dest_filename);
  $sql = "insert into _uploads_log (log_filename,log_size,log_ip) values ('$m_fname','$m_size','$m_ip')";
  $res = @mysql_query($sql);
  if (!$res) {
    $errors[] = "Could not run query.";
    break;
  }
  @mysql_free_result($res);
  @mysql_close($link);
} // if (DO_LOG)


// redirect to upload success url
header('Location: ' . SUCCESS_URL);
die();

break;

 } // while(true)

 // Errors. Show upload form.
 $message = join('',$errors);
 showUploadForm($message);

}
?>
```

I have no knowledge of PHP, so I don't know what's going wrong. I'd also like to add the capability to accept names and their email addresses.

Comment: Well, you've not said what the error is, so it's hard to be sure. But I'd wager that the added single quote in `define('DESTINATION_FOLDER','/$folder);` isn't going to help.

Comment: @andrewsi umm the error is the file does not get saved 
and thanks for pointing out :D
i'll check and tell if it works

plus i need help with the data base entry and accepting the fields like name and email

Comment: Here is a tutorial for simple php-mysql insert, begin there http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: This is one **high performance** script I'll tell ya. Even I wouldn't dare put my head in there, afraid it might bite it off.

Comment: @andrewsi i corrected the single quote but the script still does not seem to save the file
the file gets uploaded but its never there in the folder

Comment: @Fred could you suggest a simpler code
 main thing is uploading the file Data base entry is secondary

Comment: @ustone07 You can have a look at [**this one**](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/209231-php-upload/), however it's only for videos. You could modify it to accept other formats as well.

Comment: @ustone07 I am posting a form and PHP upload handler in my answer below. (Tested) That is only a basic uploading method, and there are others out there, but you will get a feel of how it works.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

*"Could you suggest a simpler code main thing is uploading the file Data base entry is secondary"*

**^--- [As per OP's request.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217964/upload-video-files-via-php-and-save-them-in-appropriate-folder-and-have-a-databa/18219669#comment26705268_18217964) ---^**

### Image and video uploading code (tested with PHP Version 5.4.17)

#### HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

#### PHP handler (upload_file.php)

Change upload folder to preferred name. Presently saves to `upload/`

```
<?php

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Videos no bigger than 20000 bytes? :-/

Comment: Why i cant upload a .MOV file.. I commented the file $extension

Comment: @Leoh (You need to) Keep that variable and try adding to the array in `$allowedExts` using both `.MOV` and `.mov` for lettercase, and check to see if the file you're trying to upload isn't too big and doesn't surpass the upload limit max. Use error reporting also. also adding to the array where `if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4") ... ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))` is located.

Comment: i did that.. i fixed with the upload limit of the server.. thanks for the help @Fred-ii

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried using this code but I am getting into the invalid file every time. I tried echoing out echo 'file type is '.$_FILES["file"]["type"].'<br>'; and it doesn't seem to have one

Comment: Every time I try to use this upload form it just says "Invalid File" result, I changed the bytes to 50000000, which is 5MB and tried a simple jpg file that was below 1MB, and made sure my server has PHP support, does anyone know why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Hi All,

So I know this is an older post, but it still is very appropriate and works great.  The only issue I am having is trying to upload from a mobile device.  It works great on regular PC, but the moment I try uploading from a mobile device I get a format not supported error.  I tried add the .mov file extension to the list of allowed, but this did not seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
HTML Code

<html>
<body>

<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
    <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>



<?php

    //============================= DATABASE CONNECTIVITY d ====================
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    else

    //============================= DATABASE CONNECTIVITY u ====================
    //============================= Retrieve data from DB d ====================
    $sql = "SELECT name, size, type FROM videos";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
        $path = "uploaded/" . $row["name"];

            echo $path . "<br>";

        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    //============================= Retrieve data from DB d ====================

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PHP file (name is upload.php)    

<?php
    // =============  File Upload Code d  ===========================================
    $target_dir = "uploaded/";

    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

     // Check file size -- Kept for 500Mb
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "wmv" && $imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "MP4") {
        echo "Sorry, only wmv, mp4 & avi files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
    // ===============================================  File Upload Code u  ==========================================================


    // =============  Connectivity for DATABASE d ===================================
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    else

    $vidname = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] . "";
    $vidsize = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] . "";
    $vidtype = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] . "";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO videos (name, size, type) VALUES ('$vidname','$vidsize','$vidtype')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {} 
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

    $conn->close();
    // =============  Connectivity for DATABASE u ===================================

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sample code:

<em><b>
<h2>Upload,Save and Download video </h2>
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="video"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/></b>
</form></em>

<?php>
include("connect.php");
$errors=1;
//Targeting Folder
$target="videos/";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//Targeting Folder 
$target=$target.basename($_FILES['video']['name']);
//Getting Selected video Type
$type=pathinfo($target,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 //Allow Certain File Format To Upload
 if($type!='mp4' && $type!='3gp' && $type!='avi'){
  echo "Only mp4,3gp,avi file format are allowed to Upload";
  $errors=0;
 }
 //checking for Exsisting video Files
  if(file_exists($target)){
   echo "File Exist";
   $errors=0;
   }
  $filesize=$_FILES['video']['size'];
  if($filesize>250*2000000){
  echo 'You Can not Upload Large File(more than 500MB) by Default ini setting..<a     href="http://www.codenair.com/2018/03/how-to-upload-large-file-in-php.html">How to   upload large file in php</a>'; 
    $errors=0;
    }
   if($errors == 0){
   echo ' Your File Not Uploaded';
    }else{
 //Moving The video file to Desired Directory
  $uplaod_success=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'],$target);
  if($uplaod_success){
  //Getting Selected video Information
    $name=$_FILES['video']['name'];
    $size=$_FILES['video']['size'];
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO VIdeos           (name,size,type)VALUES('".$name."','".$size."','".$type."')");
    if($result==TRUE){
    echo "Your video '$name' Successfully Upload and Information Saved Our  Database";
    }
   }
  }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: select from your database table you have insert value like this= ('$m_fname','$m_size','$m_ip' ) to change ('".$m_fname."','".$m_size."','".$m_ip."' ).