# File not uploaded to the server but there are no errors

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, lamp

There are no errors in my IDE, and the HTTP Response from my server is 200 OK, yet the file isn't uploaded to my server.

I am using the source code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217964/upload-video-files-via-php-and-save-them-in-appropriate-folder-and-have-a-databa/18219669#18219669) answer.

Note: I edited my php.ini to allow larger files to be uploaded.

Here's the echo result I get from upload_file.php:

```
Upload: aa.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 7.4501953125 Kb
Temp file: /tmp/phpWI6NnW
Stored in: upload/aa.jpg
```

#### HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

#### PHP handler (upload_file.php)

Change upload folder to preferred name. Presently saves to `upload/`

```
<?php

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

#### php.ini

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 200M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Comment: Where do you `close()` your `OutputStream`?

Comment: I added more code to include where I close the stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this so then it means that you have something wrong in the logic of the Web API.

Your `HttpRequest` executed correctly without any error but it might your Web API is not working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

change max file size to 20m it work for me

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Make your file/directory writable. For me, I had to set the permissions to 0777.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue though the programming was a little different with other if statements but my issue was that the file was already in the folder and my code wasn't allowing a second copy of the file. I removed the file from the uploaded folder and bam the next one was able to send through. Just something to share in case someone has this simple problem too!