# How to make a back-end service for uploading video from iPhone

Tags: php, ios, iphone, httpbackend

I want to upload an video from iPhone to Back-end server.
For this how to make a receiving part on Back-end server?
I want to make the back-end server in PHP.

Comment: Look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217964/upload-video-files-via-php-and-save-them-in-appropriate-folder-and-have-a-databa

Comment: This is rather what you want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming