# PHP Video Format Upload Issue

Tags: php, file-upload

This is my first foray into php and my project is for users to be able to upload video files to the server. I am using the following php code (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217964/upload-video-files-via-php-and-save-them-in-appropriate-folder-and-have-a-databa)) and am encountering an issue where the files upload but do not copy/save to the server. Every upload ends in the 'Invalid file' echo, despite the appropriate extensions being listed in the array. The php.ini upload settings have been increased.

Example: .mov file is being uploaded, uploads to 100%, yields invalid file echo and file isn't saved to server.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<?php

$allowedExts = array("mp4", "mpg", "mpeg", "mov", "avi", "flv", "wmv");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mov")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/avi")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/flv")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/wmv"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 3145728000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reloaded to the original script as a baseline. Uploads jpeg, png, and other image files but doesn't work with the mov video format, which is the only addition/change to the code to keep it simple. No errors are being reported, just yielding an invalid file.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="uploadtest.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP Handler:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma", "mov");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mov"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```