# How to add first name and email before uploading a video?

Tags: database, video

Hi guys im brand new and not a developer but I need a way for users when they go to my site they can upload there video and there would be a option for them to add there first name and email so when the video is uploaded the database can keep all the data together.

Ideally I want this as easy as possible for the user and this would just go to our youtube channel or any video platform will work.Any advice would be great!

Comment: You’re not asking a specific enough question that anybody is going to be be able to help you. Maybe you could provide more details about what software you’re using.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information like what platform are you using ?.

There's more than one way to skin a cat.

The simple way to achieve with web technologies like (Php,node,jave) is maintain the basic user information into the sessions, and whenever it's necessary use this information.

Comment: Sorry at this point we are thinking word press so something turnkey would be great we could just add?

Comment: Good Choice if you are not in to a coding. and maintaining a server.
here is some ready to go solutions for wordpress video blogs.
1) https://colorlib.com/wp/wordpress-video-themes/
2) http://www.inkthemes.com/wp-themes/videocraft-wordpress-theme/

Answer (score 0):

You need to get some knowledge about the system you are using. You particularly need:

- access to the server
- to know the server type
- access to the database
- to know the database type
- where the relevant files are

After you have gathered all these information, you at least know what you do not know. The next step is to gather information about how you can implement the feature you need. Look at it like at a puzzle with many small pieces. If you are patient-enough, at the end you will resolve the puzzle.

Comment: Sorry it probably will be wordpress and whatever host works best is fine with us. We really prefer a turnkey option. There must be some kind of capturing software before uploading video right?

Comment: wordpress uses mysql, so you then need to work with mysql. wordpress is a php-based technology. Uploading video with PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217964/upload-video-files-via-php-and-save-them-in-appropriate-folder-and-have-a-databa, and you need to create a form where users can fill emails and stuff: http://www.sitepoint.com/build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-plugin-in-5-minutes/, if my answer helped you, you might consider accepting it.

Comment: Also, you might consider embedding youtube videos instead of uploading files, since if many videos are uploaded, then you will need a lot of storage space.

Comment: If its being uploaded to our youtube channel (its free unlimited storage) would it be faster for the user to embed it to our site or upload it?Im not familiar with embedding only uploading/downloading?

Comment: If you provide a friendly UI and generate the embed code in the source-code, then it is faster to embed, since the user only has to upload a link, not a big audio file.