# PHP video upload occur error

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, php-ini

```
$file_name = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];

        echo $file_name;
```

When I upload the image file, it response the image's tmp_name in php server.

But I upload the video file, it doesn't response the video's tmp_name.
and I check the PHP server, in tmp folder, I can't check video's file.

Is there any condition when I upload the video file?

If you know about that, please help me.

---

I choose 2mb video file.
I think this file doesn't check limit.

Comment: Follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874406/how-can-i-upload-a-video-and-it-saved-to-a-folder-in-codeigniter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the max file upload limit in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840755/how-to-determine-the-max-file-upload-limit-in-php)

Comment: Turn on debugging, You will see errors. error_reporting('E_ALL'); ini_set('display_errors', true);

Answer (score 1):

You can check the upload_max_filesize or post_max_size property on PHP server configuration(php.ini), since the video files' sizes are usually large than the limit.
You can find relevant information below.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Thanks but I upload 2mb sample video file.