# Upload video files via PHP and have a database entry

Tags: php

I immediately apologize for my English, I live in Russia and I know English a little, sometimes I use an interpreter.
The forum already answered this question [upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217964/upload-video-files-via-php-and-save-them-in-appropriate-folder-and-have-a-databa/18219669?newreg=101fa440047c4e9086f96eeee121cb9d)

I tried the method described by Fred -ii-. When i click on the button, there was an inscription "invalid file". What could be the problem?
Ty

Comment: cope please ....

Comment: Then it would appear that the `if` statement associated with that resulted in `false`.  What was that statement checking?  When you debug, what are the values?

Comment: Hey, did you know about [this](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: just mention the video if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4") in if condition

Comment: @Don'tPanic that ru community -_-. A lot of negativity) Especially since I did not find the right answer to this question :)

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar ty

Comment: I see. Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the correct file type in this if statement, or skip the statement if you dont want a check.

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))
```