# unable to upload and play local mp4 videos to following script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, video

I found a media gallery script on w3schools but I am unable to upload my own system videos to the script and play in localhost, I tried a lot but unable to do it please help me with the  Demo: https://w3schools.in/demo/mediagallery/

I just want to play videos on my system in a gallery using the script please suggest me

**uploadmedia.php:**

```
    <?php
    include("config.php");
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Upload Media
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    if (isset($_FILES['upload_media'])) {
        /* Upload Settings Starts */
        ini_set("memory_limit", "99M");
        ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

        define('IMAGE_LARGE_DIR', './images/large/');
        define('IMAGE_LARGE_WIDTH', 800);
        define('IMAGE_LARGE_HEIGHT', 800);

        define('IMAGE_SMALL_DIR', './images/small/');
        define('IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE_WIDTH', 200);
        define('IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE_HEIGHT', 200);
        /* Upload Settings Ends */

        /* Validations Starts */
        $output['status'] = FALSE;
        $allowedImageType = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/png", "image/x-png", "video/mp4");
        if ($_FILES['upload_media']["error"] > 0) {
            $output['error'] = "Error in File";
        } elseif (!in_array($_FILES['upload_media']["type"], $allowedImageType)) {
            $output['error'] = "You can only upload JPG, PNG and GIF file";
        } elseif (round($_FILES['upload_media']["size"] / 1024) > 4000096) {
            $output['error'] = "You can upload file size up to 4 MB";
        } else {
        /* Validations Ends */

            /* create directory with 777 permission if not exist Starts */
            $obj->createDir(IMAGE_LARGE_DIR);
            $obj->createDir(IMAGE_SMALL_DIR);
            /* create directory with 777 permission if not exist Ends */

            /* Upload Settings Starts */
            $file = pathinfo($_FILES['upload_media']['name']);
            $fileType = $file["extension"];
            $desiredExt = 'jpg/mp4';
            $fileNameNew = rand(333, 999) . time() . ".$desiredExt";
            $path[1] = IMAGE_LARGE_DIR . $fileNameNew;
            $path[2] = IMAGE_SMALL_DIR . $fileNameNew;
            /* Upload Settings Ends */

            /* Upload Starts */
            if ($obj->createThumb($_FILES['upload_media']['tmp_name'], $path[1], $fileType, IMAGE_LARGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_LARGE_HEIGHT)) {
                if ($obj->createThumb($path[1], $path[2], "$desiredExt", IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE_WIDTH, IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE_WIDTH)) {
                    $output['status'] = TRUE;
                    $output['image_large'] = $path[1];
                    $output['image_small'] = $path[2];
                    $output['image_name_original'] = $file['filename'];
                    $output['media_GUID'] = rand(1111, 9999) . time();
                    /* Insert into DB */
                    $obj->addEdit('media', array('media_GUID' => $output['media_GUID'], 'media_name' => $fileNameNew, 'media_name_original' => $file['filename'], 'media_type' => $_FILES['upload_media']["type"], 'created_date' => date('Y-m-d')));
                }
            }
            /* Upload Ends */
        }
        /* Return JSON Output */
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        exit(json_encode($output));
    }

    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Upload YouTube URL
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    if (isset($_POST['youtube_id']) && $_POST['youtube_id'] != '') {
        /* Insert into DB */
        $obj->addEdit('media', array('media_GUID' => rand(1111, 9999) . time(), 'media_name' => $_POST['youtube_id'], 'media_name_original' => $_POST['youtube_id'], 'media_type' => 'YouTube', 'created_date' => date('Y-m-d')));
        $output['status'] = TRUE;
        $output['youtube_url'] = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $_POST['youtube_id'];
        $output['image_small'] = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" . $_POST['youtube_id'] . "/mqdefault.jpg";
        $output['media_name_original'] = '';
        $output['media_GUID'] = rand(1111, 9999) . time();
        /* Return JSON Output */
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        exit(json_encode($output));
    }


    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Rename Media
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    if (isset($_POST['media_name_original']) && $_POST['media_name_original'] != '') {
        /* Update into DB */
        $obj->addEdit('media', array('media_name_original' => $_POST['media_name_original']), array('media_GUID' => $_POST['media_GUID']));
    }

    ?>
```

upload.php

```
<?php include("config.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
        <title>PHP Media` Gallery Demo</title>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/app.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/photobox.css' type='text/css'>
        <!-- Font -->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- JavaScripts -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.photobox.js'></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <h1>MEDIA GALLERY DEMO, V1.0</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <hr>
            </div>
            <!-- Photo Gallery Starts -->
            <div class="row gallery">
                <?php
                $result = $obj->getGalley();
                if (!empty($result)) {
                    foreach ($result AS $row) {
                        /* IF is Video */
                        if ($row['media_type'] == 'YouTube') {
                            $rel = 'video';
                            $href = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $row['media_name'];
                            $src_bg = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $row['media_name'] . '/mqdefault.jpg';
                            $src = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $row['media_name'] . '/mqdefault.jpg';
                        } else {
                            /* IF is Image */
                            $rel = '';
                            $href = "images/large/" . $row['media_name'];
                            $src_bg = "images/small/" . $row['media_name'];
                            $src = "images/small/" . $row['media_name'];
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 gallery-block" data-media_guid="<?php echo $row['media_GUID']; ?>">
                            <div class="gallery-block-inner">  
                                <a class="photobox_a <?php if ($rel != '') { ?> media-video<?php } ?>" href="<?php echo $href; ?>" rel="<?php echo $rel; ?>" <?php if ($rel != '') { ?> style="background-image:url('images/placeholder.png'), url('<?php echo $src_bg; ?>');"<?php } ?>>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="img-responsive">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <span class="media-name"><?php echo $row['media_name_original']; ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <p id="gallery-empty">It's Empty</p>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                <!-- ProgressBar Starts -->
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 gallery-block" id="gallery-block-loader">
                    <div class="gallery-block-inner">    
                        <div id="progressbar">
                            <div class="bar percent"></div>        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ProgressBar Ends -->
            </div>
            <!-- Photo Gallery Ends -->



            <!-- Upload Media Starts -->
            <div class="row">
                <hr>
                <h3>ADD MORE MEDIA TO COLLECTION</h3>
                <div id="upload_button_group">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" id="upload_button">From My Computer</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button button-blue" id="upload_button_URL">From YouTube URL</a>
                </div>
                <form id="upload_form" name="upload_form" method="post" action="media_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" id="upload_media" name="upload_media" accept="image/*" style="display:none">
                </form>
                <form id="upload_form_url" name="upload_form_url" method="post" action="media_upload.php"  style="display:none">
                    <input class="text-field" name="youtube_url" id="youtube_url" type="text" placeholder="Please enter YouTube URL">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" id="upload_button_URL_save">Save</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button button-blue" id="upload_button_URL_cancel">Cancel</a>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Upload Media Ends -->

            <br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

config.php

```
<?php
class imageGallery {

    private $sql, $query;
    function __construct() {
        /* DB Connection */
        $this->sql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mediagallery');
    }
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Get Gallery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    function getGalley() {
        if ($query = $this->sql->query("SELECT * FROM `media` ORDER BY media_id ASC ")) {
            $rows = array();
            while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
            return $rows;
        } else {
            return "Error";
        }
    }
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Insery/Update
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    function addEdit($table_name, $data_array, $where = array()) {
        if ($table_name && is_array($data_array)) {

            if (!empty($where)) {
                /* Update */
                foreach ($data_array AS $key => $val) {
                    $value[] = $key . '=' . "'" . $this->sql->real_escape_string($val) . "'";
                }
                foreach ($where AS $key => $val) {
                    $whr[] = $key . '=' . "'" . $this->sql->real_escape_string($val) . "'";
                }
                $value = implode($value, ',');
                $whr = implode($whr, ',');
                $this->sql->query("UPDATE `$table_name` SET $value WHERE $whr");
            } else {
                /* Insert */
                foreach ($data_array AS $key => $val) {
                    $field[] = $key;
                    $value[] = "'" . $this->sql->real_escape_string($val) . "'";
                }
                $field = implode($field, ',');
                $value = implode($value, ',');
                $this->sql->query("INSERT INTO `$table_name` ($field) VALUES($value) ");
            }
        }
    }
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Create directory if not exists
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    function createDir($path) {
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            $old_mask = umask(0);
            mkdir($path, 0777, TRUE);
            umask($old_mask);
        }
    }
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Thumbnail Creation
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    function createThumb($path1, $path2, $file_type, $new_w, $new_h, $squareSize = '') {
        /* Read the source image Starts */
        $source_image = FALSE;
        if (preg_match("/jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG/", $file_type)) {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
        } elseif (preg_match("/png|PNG/", $file_type)) {
            if (!$source_image = @imagecreatefrompng($path1)) {
                $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
            }
        } elseif (preg_match("/gif|GIF/", $file_type)) {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($path1);
        }
        if ($source_image == FALSE) {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
        }
        /* Read the source image Ends */

        /* Manage Image Orientation Starts */
        $exif = @exif_read_data($path1);
        if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
            switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
                case 8:
                    $source_image = imagerotate($source_image, 90, 0);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $source_image = imagerotate($source_image, 180, 0);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $source_image = imagerotate($source_image, -90, 0);
                    break;
            }
        }
        /* Manage Image Orientation Ends */


        $orig_w = imageSX($source_image);
        $orig_h = imageSY($source_image);

        if ($orig_w < $new_w && $orig_h < $new_h) {
            $desired_width = $orig_w;
            $desired_height = $orig_h;
        } else {
            $scale = min($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);
            $desired_width = ceil($scale * $orig_w);
            $desired_height = ceil($scale * $orig_h);
        }

        if ($squareSize != '') {
            $desired_width = $squareSize;
            $desired_height = $squareSize;
        }

        /* create a new, "virtual" image */
        $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);
        /* For PNG set white background */
        $kek = imagecolorallocate($virtual_image, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefill($virtual_image, 0, 0, $kek);

        if ($squareSize == '') {
            /* copy source image at a resized size */
            imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $orig_w, $orig_h);
        } else {
            $wm = $orig_w / $desired_width;
            $hm = $orig_h / $desired_height;
            $h_height = $desired_height / 2;
            $w_height = $desired_width / 2;

            if ($orig_w > $orig_h) {
                $adjusted_width = $orig_w / $hm;
                $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
                $int_width = $half_width - $w_height;
                imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, -$int_width, 0, 0, 0, $adjusted_width, $squareSize, $orig_w, $orig_h);
            } elseif (($orig_w <= $orig_h)) {
                $adjusted_height = $orig_h / $wm;
                $half_height = $adjusted_height / 2;
                imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $adjusted_height, $orig_w, $orig_h);
            } else {
                imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $orig_w, $orig_h);
            }
        }

        if (@imagejpeg($virtual_image, $path2, 90)) {
            imagedestroy($virtual_image);
            imagedestroy($source_image);
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

}

/* Create Object */
$obj = new imageGallery();
?>
```

Comment: Do you receive any error upon uploading your videos or you simply can't upload them? Have you enabled your logger to trace what's going on in the background?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18219669/1675954

Comment: You should describe why are you unable to do it. What fails and at what point of the code it fails.

Comment: I agree with progmatico. Why do you have a desiredExt defined as 'jpg/mp4' for example? Shouldn't this be an array (or defined in allowableFileTypes)? Files of these extensions are either images or videos but not comparable types of either or. Do elaborate.

Comment: You can only upload JPG, PNG and GIF file   is the error  i am getting while trrying to upload mp4 videos

Comment: i tried with adding extensions mp4 but not working

Comment: hi script not working at all

Comment: @raghu did you follow the link that I posted? It is an answer to a question similar to yours that contains a movie upload php script. You will have to adjust it to suit your own folder/size needs but you should be able to make it work. Otherwise, please update your question (do not re-ask the same question)