# how to secure video upload php form

Tags: php, forms, video, file-upload

I have a PHP form for uploading images and videos.
I use from `getimagesize()` to secure uploading images and prevent sending fake pictures like a PHP file that have **.img** extension.

```
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "mp4") {echo"no way";}
else{
    if($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/png"){
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check == false){echo"no way";}

    if($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "video/mp4"){
    #how to secure it?
    }
    }
```

I searched a lot for function like this for videos but can not find anything to prevent sending fake video.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217964/upload-video-files-via-php-and-save-them-in-appropriate-folder-and-have-a-databa/18219669 it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, if someone really wants to trick you, you can't really be sure as they can make their file look like a video but change the data inside it.

However, to catch most cases there are generally a couple of methods:

- check the file extension (which I think you are already doing)
- check the 'magic number' - a file type identifier at the start of the file (see here for a goos example including code: https://medium.com/the-everyday-developer/detect-file-mime-type-using-magic-numbers-and-javascript-16bc513d4e1e)
- use the 'canPlayType()' on the video element in HTML5 to check if the browser can play the video - note, this will only tell you if that particular browser recognises it as a video.

Both of the second approaches are more typically JavaScript based rather than PHP as you want to do the checking in the local browser before you upload the file, and Javascript is usually the easiest way to do more complex work there.

An example of the canPlayType approach is below - you will likely get a lot of 'maybes' as it is actually hard to be 100% sure before it actually start playing. If you test you can see if it is good enough for you if you assume that anything that is not a 'NO' is 'probably' a video.

Note also that the "accept="video/*" in the input will actually quite effective checking for you also, depending on the implementation in the particular browser and OS combination - the behaviour changes subtly between combinations. Again, it is worth experimenting to see if this alone is good enough for your needs.

```js
(function localVideoCheck() {
 'use strict'

  var checkVideo = function (event) {
    var file = this.files[0]
    var type = file.type
    var videoNode = document.querySelector('video');
    var canPlayResult = videoNode.canPlayType(type);
    if (canPlayResult === "")  {
      canPlayResult = "No"
    }
    alert(canPlayResult);
  }

  var inputNode = document.querySelector('input');
  inputNode.addEventListener('change', checkVideo, false);
  })()
```

```html
<h1>Local video file check</h1>
<input type="file" accept="video/*"/>
<div hidden>
  <video controls autoplay></video>
</div>
```