# How to convert the PHP Photo Upload /images for PHP video upload /videos?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, debugging, image-uploading

My Php class for photos is:

```
class Photo extends Db_object{


    protected static $db_table = "photos";
    protected static $db_table_fields = array('photo_id', 'title', 'description', 'filename', 'type', 'size');
    public $photo_id;
    public $title;
    public $description;
    public $filename;
    public $type;
    public $size;


    public $tmp_path;
    public $upload_directory = "images";
    public $custom_errors = array();
    public $upload_errors_array = array(


    UPLOAD_ERR_OK => "There is no error",
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize",
    UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE => "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive",
    UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL => "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => "No file was uploaded.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => "Missing a temporary folder.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => "Failed to write file to disk.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION => "A PHP extension stopped the file upload."
);
```

And the upload form is

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php
    //check if there was an error and print out the error

    if(!empty($upload_errors)){
        echo $the_message;
    }
    ?>


    <input type="file" name="file_upload"><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

So i've never uploaded a video before and used a  or whatever tag that is. Can anyone point to a tutorial that is not javasript and backend drag and drop video files? Specifically uploaded the file with .avi, mp4 and so on? I realize that photo uploads allows gifs so that could work but I am looking for a mvc hard coded approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not quite understand your logic but if you want to upload a video and save the information you want in your database you can use some library in javascript (Jquery) like : [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for upload (front-end side) and use the global variable $ _FILES **(look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18219669/8489245))** to extract the information you need!