# How to insert images and videos into databases

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery

i'm going to create a gallery website and it will contain a lot of
alboums and photos, videos. now what the right thing: 1-insert the photos and videos in database (if it right tell me how) 2-make an html page for each alboum. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add site name and are you connect website with database

Comment: Lookup for Binary Large Object in Google. Also lookup how to upload files via http.

Comment: Are you using php, python, java, ASP.Net...on the server side?

Comment: @Rayees AC, i didn't finish the website yet

Comment: @Tarik , i using php

Comment: Ok, first figure out how to upload a file and grab it via your php script. You could first save the uploaded file to a local file on your server. Once this works, read an example on how to put a blob in MySql. Combine these two and you got what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217964/upload-video-files-via-php-and-save-them-in-appropriate-folder-and-have-a-databa/18219669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure The "php.ini" File

First, ensure that PHP is configured to allow file uploads.

In your "php.ini" file, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On:

```
file_uploads = On
```

Create The `HTML Form`

Next, create an HTML form that allow users to choose the image file they want to upload:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Some rules to follow for the HTML form above:

Make sure that the form uses `method="post"`. The form also needs the following attribute: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. It specifies which content-type to use when submitting the form

Without the requirements above, the file upload will not work.

Other things to notice:

The `type="file"` attribute of the `<input>` tag shows the input field as a file-select control, with a "Browse" button next to the input control

The form above sends data to a file called **"upload.php"**, which we will create next.
Create **The Upload File PHP Script**

The "upload.php" file contains the code for uploading a file:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}
?>
```

more info :

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

https://sites.google.com/site/prgimr/how-to-upload-image-or-files-into-database-using-php-and-mysql

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OUTgnaezNY

Answer (score 0):

Third option probably is the best. Store them in a cloud storage like AWS S3, Azure Blob Storage or Google Cloud Storage and many other options. They are much cheaper than a database and more versatile then storing as html.

Comment: Early optimization... Maybe just a homework or something.